# Do Double Damage rune stack?

Tags: dota-2, dota

If I was able to bottle a rune of *Double Damage* at around **1:55** and after I waited in the same rune spot, another Double Damage rune appears and I took it and use also the rune in my bottle, will it stack?

Does my damage will become quadruple?

It's hard to do this since I can hardly get a chance of having a DD rune appear consecutively.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

Double Damage runes take into account only pure hero damage and attribute damage items (except for pure damage items like Divine Rapier).

They do not stack for other damage increasing abilities (Earthshaker and Enchant Totem, Sven and God's Strength etc).

Answer (score 4):

Double damage is a buff.
You can't have 2 times the same buff, taking the DD again will just reset the duration.

Answer (score 1):

The same rune can't spawn twice in a row.

It's still possible to bottle a rune right before another spawns, then activate it just before the 3rd spawns such that you'd have two DD runes activated.

I'm not sure if it's a boolean (true or false) state or if they stack on top of each other so that you could have two active at the same time, but even if they did you'd only get triple damage, not quadruple damage, as the only things that are doubled are your base damage plus your modified primary attribute.

Comment: I think it is treated as a flat buff (as indicated by the rune icon) so unless they were intentionally programmed to stack, they won't. I'm guessing the duration would just get reset.

Comment: @Decency "The same rune can't spawn twice in a row." when this happened? If I could I would have shown you bunch of games where regen spawns at the same side about 6-8 times

Comment: @GeoStrike http://store.steampowered.com/news/7155/

Answer (score 0):

Unstackable. It will simply reset the duration to max.